# Sending RAW JSON to Content-Type multipart/form-data in Postman

Tags: .net-6.0

I want to test an API using Postman. I have 6 collections folder, in the 3 folders I call this API with the same request. If I use key-value pair, it will take times when there is a change in the request. So I put the request in collections variable as RAW JSON, but when I use this, the API returns Bad Request (400).

I'm using .NET 6 Web API, and my API look like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] TestViewModel vm)
{
    // Process Data
}
```

For the notes, I use [FromForm] because I have file input in the form.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to post json to api it's better to user [FromBody] attribute, if you want to use [FromForm] you must use key-value form in form-data in postman.
for converting your model to json to store in collection use Newtonsoft.Json package.

Comment: I have file input in the view, but I don't want to send file in Postman

Comment: before calling api you must open json file with javaScript or typeScript and read json data then fill model.property then call api

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps to send data as FromForm in Postman

Request Type: Post

In body select **form-body or x-www-form-urlencoded** send data as key value pairs. Class property as Key and value is your Requested Data

[image]

Comment: Sorry my questions is not clear, I already update my question. I already used key-value pair before, but I have 3 calls for this API in different folder with same request, so I want to make it easy to maintain. So I put the request in collection variable as RAW JSON

Comment: if you want to use Raw Json use **[FromBody]** instead of **[FromForm]**

Comment: I have file input in the form, so I must use [FromForm]

Comment: for single object  object.Proparty   eg: Details.Firstname if list of objects use indexing like eg Details[0].FirstName. this way u can send send child data

Comment: above process may help you. change the keys accordingly in postman

Comment: So there is no others workaround besides using this key-value pair? right now I already use key-value pair, but it hard to maintains because when there is change in the request I must change all the request for this API

Comment: that's the only way to send Form Data through Postman. If u include Swagger also in that you will get text box for each property

Comment: Use Bulk Edit Option in Postman it's also key value pair but you can copy and past the data. Which is also look like JSON sample 
**FirstName:Upender
LastName:Reddy
Det.FirstName:test
Det.LastName:test2**